# Sabre developer api - how limited is the data in development? Am I using it wrong or is data THAT limited?

Tags: sabre, sabredav

Im trying our different flight api's from sabre, I understand from reading the data Im getting back is limited in development but Im not sure if it really can be THAT limited or its me doing something wrong.

1: InstaFlights Search

First I use the citypairs lookup to show city pairs, then use them for the instasearch,

The problem is unlike I use NY or London (there were 2 other cities working fine), for almost ALL other cities, Im getting no response.
I know data is limited but since the citypairs api already returns VERY limited data, but is it really THAT limited? Feeling like I must be doing something wrong because I cannot image, that api to work (in dev) only for 3 cities on 3 different dates :-/

2. destination api
   here I use first the supported cities api, then use results to use the multi airports api, then use that for destination api.

Again, same here, only 2/3 cities actually work. Since in the destination api, UNLIKE the instaflights api, the changes of 'matches' are higher as any destination could be shown for the picked origin. HERE AGAIN almost no results, BUT for about 3 cities.

If anyone who has some experience with sabre, could help out it would be great- just trying to figure out if its me whos using it wrong or no. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide the city pairs that seem to be failing for you? I just did a test of both APIs (InstaFlights and DestinationFinder) and was able to obtain results with the city pairs provided there. I changed the point of sale to FR and obtained PAR-ATH, and that worked. Also worked with ABE-MCO which is the first city pair I obtain when using POS US.

The testing environment for this API but you should be not limited to just three cities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For example (and there are many more examples as most cities dont work): for the destinations finder, I try bangkok - param values: code: BKK, departuredate: 2018-01-20, returndate:  2018-01-26. another one is Berlin: code: TXL, date same as for bangkok, atlantic city with code: AIY, MELBOURNE WITH CODE MEL- Im getting a 404 Not Found.. I dont think that I need to provide a point of sale- when I try JFK for example (one of the very view places where I am getting a response) I dont need that.